# Fix a font size for .NET GUI

Tags: .net, font-size

Depending on the font settings (DPI and such) on the user's computers, I can have text become too big to fit in a button and moves down to the next line (wrap), so if it is a small button that says "Do xyz", it will only show "Do" unless I increase the height on the user's computer, but it looks fine on mine.

Is there any way to force it to stick to original font size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: You shouldn't. The whole point of the user choosing how large their UI should be is that the UI will do exactly that.

You can, however, set the [`AutoScaleMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode.aspx) property on the form to `None` to prevent scaling. You can't set this directly on the button, though.

Depending how cramped your UI is you may want to consider simply setting the button's [`AutoSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.autosize.aspx) property along with `MinimumSize` and `MaximumSize` to allow it to grow automatically if the text gets larger.